# static analysis for identifying backdoors in PE

Tags: reverse-engineering, backdoor

I am doing research in identifying backdoors in Windows .exe files. Currently I found some methods to detect them:

1. String search in .exe
2. Find reference .dll and win32 API calls using import table

What are other static analysis methods to detect backdoors?

Comment: You've basically asked the same question 3 times. Let's focus on the one with answers.